# Sending info from rest API to arduino correct encoding

Tags: javascript, arduino, bluetooth

Hi I am trying to send simple data to my Arduino car to make it drive, simple values like 1 2 or 3.

It works fine when I send with coolterm, I can control my car with values there.

But when I try with my rest API code I can't get it so send data to my car, or it receives it in wrong format.

```
const axios = require("axios");
const moment = require("moment");
const SerialPort = require('serialport')
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.HC-05-DevB', {
 baudRate: 9600
})


Const XMLOPEN_URL = "censored";
const INTERVAL = 4000;

Function looper(fn, interval) {
 interval = interval || DEFAULT_INTERVAL;
 const loop = function () {
    fn()
      .then(() => {
        setTimeout(loop, interval);
      })
 }
 return loop;
}

Function fetchAndProcessTrainData(URL) {
 return axios
    .get(URL)
    .then(({ data }) => {
      //Handling error in case of data is not available
      const arr = ((data || {}).MultiDepartureBoard || {}).Departure || [];
      return arr.filter(e => {
        if (!e.rtTime) {
          return false;
        }
        let timeParsed = moment(e.time, "HH:mm");
        let rtTimeParsed = moment(e.rtTime, "HH:mm");
        let timeDiff = rtTimeParsed.diff(timeParsed, 'minutes');
        e.timeDiff = timeDiff;
        return true;
      });

    })
    .catch(e => {
      throw e;
    })
}

Const loopFunction = looper(() => {
 console.clear();
 console.log('---------------');
 return fetchAndProcessTrainData(XMLOPEN_URL)
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.timeDiff);
        port.write(Buffer.from(element.timeDiff('utf-8'))
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      // console.error(`Error: ${err.message}`);
      return err;
    })
}, INTERVAL);

LoopFunction();
```

Comment: So the Arduino part / code is working, but the REST API code is not working? What is your code running on and what kind of IDE / editor did you use to write it?

Comment: Yes the arduino part is working I can send data from coolterm like "1" or so, and my arduino car will move.. 

I am using node JS in terminal to run it - and it's coded sublime text

Comment: `receives it in wrong format` is a very poor descriotion of the received data .... it provides no information that could be used to determine the area of failure

Comment: How can I elaborate it better?

Comment: Can you print to the Serial monitor from the Arduino, to see if the values received are correct? I'm trying to determine which general area the problem is in. If the issue is Arduino related, it's on-topic for our site. If not, we should migrate the question to a different Stack Exchange site.

Comment: you can elaborate better by stating what is actually received

Comment: It's numbers that my arduino receives, I think I should move this further to a different stack exhchange site.

Comment: another SE site will ask you the same questions  ... they will also want to know what `receives it in wrong format` means

Comment: I found out I have convert element.timeDiff to binary somehow with Number.toString(2)